# Lazy Loading in EF 5.0 beta 2 doesn't matter?

Tags: entity-framework-5

I just downloaded and installed the brand new Entity Framework 5.0 beta 2 which was released yesterday. Now, in my EDMX model file, it doesn't matter wether or not I set "Lazy loading enabled" to true or false.

I still need to "Include" the association properties that I want to use for the retrieved objects.

Can anyone explain why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up fixing this issue by (sadly) making a class which inherits my ModelContainer. In this class' constructor, I set the settings to enable lazy loading - even though it was already set in my EDMX file itself.

This worked just fine. Strange issue indeed.